# PHP authentication can not be done because of changing hosting

Tags: php, authentication, header

The code blow was used for authenticatin for a page (it is snippet of whole page but the main idea is here):

```
 if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MX Administration\"");
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit;
  } 
  else {
        session_start();
        if( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == $login && md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) == $password ){

                if( $_SESSION['adm'] == '' && empty($_POST) ){
                    header("Location: whmcs.php");
                    exit;
                }
                elseif( $_SESSION['adm'] == '' && !empty($_POST) ){

                    if(  $_POST['login'] == $login_in &&  md5($_POST['password']) == $password_in ){
                        $_SESSION['adm']="OK";  
                    }
                    else{
                        header("Location: whmcs.php?do=message");
                        exit;
                    }
                 }
                 else{
                    $_SESSION['adm']="OK";
                 }

        }
        else{
            header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"MX Administration\"");
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
            echo ":)\n";
            exit;
        }
  }

?>
```

Now when I have transfered this code to another server, it does not authenticate, it always asks for username, password. I guess it is because of php version, php config. What you think what may br the reason. (I am sure that I am writing the correct username and password.)

Comment: Check out the logs, see what may be happening!?

Comment: check Apache's error like this `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the reason is CGI API used to run PHP scripts.
You have to either change API to mod_php or change hosting or change HTTP auth to sessions

Comment: Most webservers still allow you to pass the header through configuration.